# Intent ACTION_SENDTO in GMAIL with UNDO

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail

In a personal application I use an INTENT ACTION_SENDTO to send an email to several recipients.

The basic code is as follows:

```
        Intent Mail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        Mail.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + addresses));
        startActivity(Mail);
```

This code works and opens GMAIL (which is the default app on my phone).
However I notice a difference if I use my application to open GMAIL or if I open GMAIL directly.
Indeed if I send an email directly via GMAIL I have an option (for X seconds) to cancel the sending of the message. A Pop-Up/Toast appears and allows you to cancel the send.

Going through my application and the INTENT, this option does not appear. When the message is sent, the window closes directly and I return to my application without this pop-up/Toast.

Is it possible to add this option, which I find very practical, via the INTENT?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: `Intent ACTION_SENDTO in GMAIL with UNDO` Intent ACTION_SENDTO in GMAIL with user conformation?

Comment: I am not sur to understand, but it's not a confirmation.
It is the possibilty to undo the send of the email. Gmail can do that but i don't have this possibility when i send a enmail from the intent